# AIX 7.1 Creating an enhanced JFS file system issues?

Tags: storage, aix, lvm

I am fairly new to AIX and am trying to create my first jfs file system mounted on /usr1.

I started off by creating my volume group from the available disks..

```
#/usr/sbin/mklv -y'vl_usr1' -t'jfs2' -c'2' vg_usr1 6005
van-oppy# lsvg vg_usr1
VOLUME GROUP:       vg_usr1                  VG IDENTIFIER:  000015010000d60000000140f464119b
VG STATE:           active                   PP SIZE:        128 megabyte(s)
VG PERMISSION:      read/write               TOTAL PPs:      12012 (1537536 megabytes)
MAX LVs:            256                      FREE PPs:       2 (256 megabytes)
LVs:                1                        USED PPs:       12010 (1537280 megabytes)
OPEN LVs:           0                        QUORUM:         12 (Enabled)
TOTAL PVs:          22                       VG DESCRIPTORS: 22
STALE PVs:          0                        STALE PPs:      0
ACTIVE PVs:         22                       AUTO ON:        yes
MAX PPs per VG:     32512
MAX PPs per PV:     1016                     MAX PVs:        32
LTG size (Dynamic): 256 kilobyte(s)          AUTO SYNC:      no
HOT SPARE:          no                       BB POLICY:      relocatable

PV RESTRICTION:     none                     INFINITE RETRY: noegabytes)
OPEN LVs:           2                        QUORUM:         3 (Enabled)
TOTAL PVs:          4                        VG DESCRIPTORS: 4
STALE PVs:          0                        STALE PPs:      0
ACTIVE PVs:         4                        AUTO ON:        yes
MAX PPs per VG:     32768                    MAX PVs:        1024
LTG size (Dynamic): 256 kilobyte(s)          AUTO SYNC:      no
HOT SPARE:          no                       BB POLICY:      relocatable
MIRROR POOL STRICT: off
PV RESTRICTION:     none                     INFINITE RETRY: no
```

Below is the lslv of the logical volume...

```
# lslv vl_usr1
LOGICAL VOLUME:     vl_usr1                VOLUME GROUP:   vg_usr1
LV IDENTIFIER:      000015010000d60000000140f464119b.1 PERMISSION:     read/write
VG STATE:           active/complete        LV STATE:       closed/syncd
TYPE:               jfs2                   WRITE VERIFY:   off
MAX LPs:            6005                   PP SIZE:        128 megabyte(s)
COPIES:             2                      SCHED POLICY:   parallel
LPs:                6005                   PPs:            12010
STALE PPs:          0                      BB POLICY:      relocatable
INTER-POLICY:       minimum                RELOCATABLE:    yes
INTRA-POLICY:       middle                 UPPER BOUND:    32
MOUNT POINT:        N/A                    LABEL:          None
MIRROR WRITE CONSISTENCY: on/ACTIVE
EACH LP COPY ON A SEPARATE PV ?: yes
Serialize IO ?:     NO
INFINITE RETRY:     no
```

When creating the logical volume i've set it to have 2 copies, so now my free LPs is 6005.

When I try next to create an enhanced JFS2 file system it fails..

```
                    Add an Enhanced Journaled File System

Type or select values in entry fields.
Press Enter AFTER making all desired changes.

[TOP]                                                   [Entry Fields]
Volume group name                                   vg_usr1
SIZE of file system
        Unit Size                                   Megabytes              +
*         Number of units                            [768640]                 #
* MOUNT POINT                                        [/usr1]
Mount AUTOMATICALLY at system restart?              yes                    +
PERMISSIONS                                         read/write             +
Mount OPTIONS                                      []                      +
Block Size (bytes)                                  4096                   +
Logical Volume for Log                                                     +
Inline Log size (MBytes)                           []                       #
Extended Attribute Format                                                  +
ENABLE Quota Management?                            no                     +
[MORE...3]

F1=Help             F2=Refresh          F3=Cancel           F4=List
Esc+5=Reset         Esc+6=Command       Esc+7=Edit          Esc+8=Image
Esc+9=Shell         Esc+0=Exit          Enter=Do
```

The commit fails with..

```
0516-404 allocp: This system cannot fulfill the allocation request. There are not enough free partitions or not enough physical volumes to keep strictness and satisfy allocation requests.  The command should be retried with different allocation characteristics.
0516-822 mklv: Unable to create logical volume.
crfs: 0506-972 Cannot create logical volume for file system.
rmlv: Logical volume loglv00 is removed.
```

I am confused as to why? My free PPs was 6005, so 6005 x 128 = 768640mb which is what I set during the creation. I also tried to lower the number to 768000mb which is 6000 PPs but still no go.

Any AIX experts out there able to shed some light as to why this is not working? Trying to wrap my head around how the LVM works...

Comment: I have resolved my issue, I was allocating more space than available and using wrong calculations to come up with the maximum available.

Comment: Could you post that as an answer to your question then?

Comment: ah yes, select the add comment instead of answer question button, than for that.

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved my issue, I was allocating more space than available and using wrong calculations to come up with the maximum available.